# How to create a 2 stacked specific column layout in Flex at a particular breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to use Flex to change the layout of my grid at a particular breakpoint. I have attached what I need it to look like at 900px and above.

I just can not figure out how to get the columns to align and stack under each other.

Here is a fiddle and code below:
http://jsfiddle.net/3wk9yepj/

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 32px 0;

  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 900px) {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    // here needs to be the new layout from screenshot attached
  }
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 32px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box-2 {
  width: 50%;
}

.box-3 {
  width: 50%;
  background: grey;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  /* object-fit: contain; */
  height: 100%;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h4>
      Title goes here
    </h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-2">
    <img src="https://www.audi.com/content/dam/gbp2/models/1920x1080-desktop-models-teaser-A211437.jpg?imwidth=1920&imdensity=1" />
  </div>

  <div class="box-3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using flex rather than grid?

Comment: Im not against grid, as i've never really used it before. If its easier to do in grid, I'm all for that. Just thought it wouldn't be this tricky with flex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a `grid`-layout, you can use `grid-template-columns` to set your desired amount of columns.

Below I've used this property to create a 2 column layout, where the first column is 60% of the entire width of the `.wrapper`-element, while the second column is 40% of the entire width of the `.wrapper`-element. You can use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` for equal width columns if you want to.

```css
grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
```

You can use the property `grid-row: span 2` to let `.box-1` span its height to 2 rows.

For equal height rows, apply `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;`.

When you want to make `.box-1` wrap, you can just use a media query:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 32px 0;
  display: grid;
  /* set 2 columns */
  /* equal width columns */
  /* grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; */
  grid-template-columns: 60% 40%;
  /* equal height */
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 40px 32px;
  width: 100%;
  /* span 2 rows */
  grid-row: span 2;
}

.box-3 {
  background: grey;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .wrapper {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .box-1 {
    grid-row: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box-1">
    <h4>
      Title goes here
    </h4>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="box-2">
    <img src="https://www.audi.com/content/dam/gbp2/models/1920x1080-desktop-models-teaser-A211437.jpg?imwidth=1920&imdensity=1" />
  </div>

  <div class="box-3">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh brill, just wondering how i would keep my other two layouts as well as this though? On my fiddle if you resize the screen you can see the other two layouts